# Could not deduce (Dim n0)

Tags: haskell, dependent-type, type-level-computation

I want to build a Hilbert matrix using the linear package and convert it to a list of lists. While this seems an easy task the type level constraints come into my way:

```
import Linear
import Linear.V
import Data.Vector qualified as V

-- | Outer (tensor) product of two vectors
outerWith :: (Functor f, Functor g, Num a) => (a -> a -> a) -> f a -> g a -> f (g a)
{-# INLINABLE outerWith #-}
outerWith f a b = fmap (\x -> fmap (f x) b) a

hilbertV :: forall a n. (Fractional a, Dim n) => Integer -> V n (V n a)
hilbertV n =
  let v = V $ V.fromList $ fromIntegral <$> [1..n]
      w = V $ V.fromList $ fromIntegral <$> [0..n-1]
  in luInv $ outerWith (+) w v

listsFromM :: V n (V n a) -> [[a]]
listsFromM m = vToList (vToList <$> m)

vToList :: V n a -> [a]
vToList = V.toList . toVector

hilbertL :: forall a. (Fractional a) => Integer -> [[a]]
hilbertL n = listsFromM (hilbertV n)
```

When doing this the following error arises in the last line `hilbertL n = listsFromM (hilbertV n)`:

```
bench/Solve.hs:28:26: error:
    • Could not deduce (Dim n0) arising from a use of ‘hilbertV’
      from the context: Fractional a
        bound by the type signature for:
                   hilbertL :: forall a. Fractional a => Integer -> [[a]]
        at bench/Solve.hs:27:1-56
      The type variable ‘n0’ is ambiguous
      These potential instances exist:
        three instances involving out-of-scope types
          instance GHC.TypeNats.KnownNat n => Dim n -- Defined in ‘Linear.V’
          instance Data.Reflection.Reifies s Int =>
                   Dim (Linear.V.ReifiedDim s)
            -- Defined in ‘Linear.V’
          instance forall k (n :: k) a. Dim n => Dim (V n a)
            -- Defined in ‘Linear.V’
    • In the first argument of ‘listsFromM’, namely ‘(hilbertV n)’
      In the expression: listsFromM (hilbertV n)
      In an equation for ‘hilbertL’: hilbertL n = listsFromM (hilbertV n)
```

How can i get this to compile?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, the type of `HilbertV` is unsafe. You shouldn't pass in an `Integer` size if size should be determined from the type! I think you want this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications, UnicodeSyntax #-}

hilbertV :: ∀ a n. (Fractional a, Dim n) => V n (V n a)
hilbertV = luInv $ outerWith (+) w v
 where v = V $ V.fromList $ fromIntegral <$> [1..n]
       w = V $ V.fromList $ fromIntegral <$> [0..n-1]
       n = reflectDim @n []
```

(The `[]` just fills the proxy argument with the most concise way to generate a value-less functor input, since it is easier to pass in the type information with `-XTypeApplications`.)

In fact, I'd avoid even passing around `n` twice at all. Instead, why not factor out the marginal generation:

```
hilbertV :: ∀ a n. (Fractional a, Dim n) => V n (V n a)
hilbertV = luInv $ outerWith (+) w v
 where v = fromIntegral <$> enumFinFrom 1
       w = fromIntegral <$> enumFinFrom 0

enumFinFrom :: ∀ n a . (Enum a, Dim n) => a -> V n a
enumFinFrom ini = V . V.fromList $ take (reflectDim @n []) [ini..]
```

Now, for `hilbertL` the problem is that you have a *dependent type* size. The trick to deal with that are Rank2-quantified functions; `linear` offers `reifyDim`/`reifyVector` etc. for the purpose.

```
hilbertL :: ∀ a . Fractional a => Int -> [[a]]
hilbertL n = reifyDim n hilbertL'
 where hilbertL' :: ∀ n p . Dim n => p n -> [[a]]
       hilbertL' _ = listsFromM $ hilbertV @n
```

Alternatively, you could also change `hilbertV` to take a proxy argument for the size and then just hand that in. I've always found this a bit ugly, but it's actually more compact in this case:

```
hilbertV :: ∀ a n p . (Fractional a, Dim n) => p n -> V n (V n a)
hilbertV np = luInv $ outerWith (+) w v
 where v = V $ V.fromList $ fromIntegral <$> [1..n]
       w = V $ V.fromList $ fromIntegral <$> [0..n-1]
       n = reflectDim np

hilbertL :: ∀ a . Fractional a => Int -> [[a]]
hilbertL n = reifyDim n (\np -> listsFromM $ hilbertV np)
```

Comment: This seems to be a great answer apart from some minor issues. First I got an error that the type variable `p` is missing and I added as follows: `hilbertL' :: ∀ n (p :: Type -> Type) . Dim n => p n -> Int -> [[a]]`. Or should `p` be in fact `Proxy`?

But then I get the following error and I am lost again, sorry:

`
    • Couldn't match kind ‘k1’ with ‘Type’
      When matching types
        p0 :: k -> Type
        [] :: Type -> Type
...
   |
28 | enumFinFrom ini = V . V.fromList $ take (reflectDim @n []) [ini..]
   |                                                        ^^
`

Comment: Next, maybe instead of `hilbertL' :: ∀ n (p :: Type -> Type) . Dim n => p n -> Int -> [[a]]` it should be `hilbertL' :: ∀ n (p :: Type -> Type) . Dim n => p n -> [[a]]`?

Comment: Sure, edited. Specializing it to `Proxy` would work as well, but there's a semi-convention to make proxy _arguments_ polymorphic and proxy results specific to `Proxy`. I don't think there's a deep reason for this, but it does allow the trick of passing `[]`.